# OpenApi Generator kotlin how to make Interface classes non-parcelable (or non-model), while other data classes are parcelable

Tags: kotlin, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

OpenApi-Generator version: 6.6.0
Generator: Kotlin

I am trying to get inheritance with OpenApi generator to generate kotlin classes.

1. Base class yaml (Not sure how to make 'open class'; but using discriminator creates interface class)
   I realized adding mapping doesn't create much difference in generated code
   Using oneOf adds the properties from derived class as well, which is not needed in my case

```
properties:
  id:
    type: string
    format: uuid
#oneOf:
#  - $ref: './NetworkError.yaml'
#  - $ref: './ReaderError.yaml'
discriminator:
  propertyName: type
#  mapping:
#    NetworkError: './NetworkError.yaml'
#    ReaderError: './ReaderError.yaml'

title: ErrorOverrides
type: object
```

Derived class yaml...Same way other classes that will be derived from the same base class /interface

```
description: An error object
allOf:
  - $ref: './ErrorOverrides.yaml'
  - properties:
      code:
        $ref: './NetworkErrorCode.yaml'
title: NetworkError
type: object
```

Config yaml

```
generatorName: kotlin
additionalProperties:
  serializationLibrary: gson
  enumPropertyNaming: UPPERCASE
  library: jvm-volley
  sortParamsByRequiredFlag: false
  parcelizeModels: true
  artifactory_publish: true
  modelMutable: true
#  useOneOfDiscriminatorLookup: true
```

Now the code generated is:
(I could remove AllOf generated class using .openapi-generator-ignore class)

```
@Parcelize
interface ErrorOverrides : Parcelable {

    @get:SerializedName("id")
    var id: java.util.UUID?
}
```

```
@Parcelize
data class NetworkError (

    @SerializedName("id")
    override var id: java.util.UUID? = null,

    @SerializedName("code")
    var code: NetworkErrorCode? = null

) : ErrorOverrides, Parcelable
```

**The major problem is: It should not be both parcelable and interface. I cannot remove parcelable property from my config file..so either it should not be treated as model class or there is another way to not to make it parcelable for this class**

It can be something similar to skip serialization/parcelization in one file; but even for that I couldn't find any solution